# Unit testing custom STL-compatible containers and iterators

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, stl, c++17

I've just implemented a custom iterator type for a custom container. The container models the C++17 [*ReversibleContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ReversibleContainer), and its iterators (both const and non-const) model [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

My question is; is there some sort of built-in thing in `std` that I can use to test if both the container and its iterators adhere to the specified named requirements, or do I have to write all the tests myself (which is mostly doable for me but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel; and also I'm not sure I'm enough of a template wizard to really thoroughly prove that e.g. types and such are correct)?

Things like (I know this is one of many), e.g. this from the operational semantics of `operator <`:

```
custom_container::iterator a = ...;
custom_container::iterator b = ...;
assert((a < b) == (b - a > 0));
```

And that return types are correct, etc., and such.

---

I've managed to find *some* capabilities already, for example *<type_traits>* has some useful utilities like:

```
if (!std::is_copy_constructible<custom_container::iterator>::value)
   /* fail test */ ;
```

Which is good for some of the fundamental named requirements at least.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but note that `assert((it -= n) == (it += -n))` won't actually work. Meaning, the test will fail if the iterator is implemented correctly, since it's comparing `it - n` to `it - 2*n`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oops; let me clean that up. Thanks.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What? That test is bogus, but for a different reason: Both compound-assignments return a reference to `it`, and iterators should be self-equal.

Comment: @Deduplicator True. For some reason I thought it would return a value.

Comment: It's moot now I changed the test to something I can handle without coffee.

Comment: But if you are testing without coffee, you are not properly simulating real-world conditions.

Comment: Ok; I've made some progress; <type_traits> has some useful stuff like `if (std::is_copy_constructible<custom_container::iterator>::value) { ... }`; which is a good start for some of the more fundamental named requirements.

Comment: That of course only checks that the class supports the correct syntax, not that it actually implements the correct semantics when that syntax is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there us not.

In fact proving a type satisfies all requirements of being an iterator cannot be done statically in C++.

You can test statically if the types are correct, and that operators and the like exist. But ths semantics cannot be proven in the general case (I think both practically and theoretically due to Rice's theorem).

I find most of the requirements are easy to check in practice (if not as easy to automate).  The most common gotcha I find is that "legacy" iterators stronger than input iterators must have actual backing persistent data they return references and pointers to; that data cannot live within the iterator, or be otherwise temporary/generated.